# Is there a way to set fixed metadata for docx files by using Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, metadata, docx

I want to prepare some reference docx file for tests. This file contains a set of strings in a specific order.

There are some REST APIs, by calling which I get files as byte arrays and in my tests I want to compare them with the reference file.

To generate docx files, I use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) library. For example:

```
...
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph title = document.createParagraph();
title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

XWPFRun titleRun = title.createRun();
titleRun.setFontFamily("Arial");
titleRun.setFontSize(11);

for (int i = 0; i < fileNames.size(); i++) {
    titleRun.setText(format("%d. %s", (i + 1),  fileNames.get(i)));
    titleRun.addBreak();
}
...
```

Here I need to set a fixed metadata. I do it by this way:

```
@SneakyThrows
private void clearDocxMetadata(XWPFDocument document) {
    CoreProperties props = document.getProperties().getCoreProperties();
    props.setCreated("2019-08-14T21:00:00z");
    props.setLastModifiedByUser(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    props.setCreator(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    props.setLastPrinted("2019-08-14T21:00:00z");
    props.setModified("2019-08-14T21:00:00z");

    document.getProperties().commit();
}
```

REST APIs uses the same code to generate docx files and I believe that the metadata will be freezed.

However, the generated files sometimes changes and byte arrays equality tests gives the following:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array contents differ at index [10], expected: <-3> but was: <98>
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array contents differ at index [10], expected: <-3> but was: <97>
```

The contents of the files are identical:

[image]

But in hex mode I see the differences:

[image]

Unpacked core.xml of referenced docx file from \docProps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cp:coreProperties 
    xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2019-08-14T00:00:00Z</dcterms:created>
   <dc:creator>2019-08-14T21:00:00z</dc:creator>
   <cp:lastModifiedBy>2019-08-14T21:00:00z</cp:lastModifiedBy>
   <cp:lastPrinted>2019-08-14T00:00:00Z</cp:lastPrinted>
   <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2019-08-14T00:00:00Z</dcterms:modified>
</cp:coreProperties>
```

It looks like some metadata is changing (most likely it is a date).

If I set the metadata in the tests code, it also has no effect:

```
@SneakyThrows
private void setCustomDocxMetadata(InputStream inputStream, Date date) {
    try (OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(inputStream)) {
        PackageProperties docxMetadata = opc.getPackageProperties();
        docxMetadata.setModifiedProperty(Optional.of(date));
        docxMetadata.setCreatedProperty(Optional.of(date));
        docxMetadata.setLastModifiedByProperty(StringUtils.EMPTY);
        docxMetadata.setCreatorProperty(StringUtils.EMPTY);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set fixed metadata for docx files by using Apache POI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences you have found are the last modified file date and time of the entries in the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive. This has nothing to do with the file properties you set already.

Accorrding to [ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers) this are exactly the bytes you have marked in your hex dump. A entry starts at 0 with 4 bytes `504B0304` and at offset 10 are 2 bytes for last modified time and at offset 12 are 2 bytes for last modified date.

The modified file date and time of the entries in the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive is set when the `XWPFDocument` is written out and the  `*.docx` `ZIP` archive containig the entries is created. There is no proper way getting into this process.

The only way I have found is, creating a temporary `ZIP` file from the data after the documents were written out. Then using `java.util.zip.*` for maipulating the last modified file date and time of all the entries in the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import java.util.zip.*;

public class CreateXWPFFixedZIPCreationDateTime {

 static byte[] createXWPFZIPArchive() throws Exception {
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The content");
  clearDocxMetadata(document);

  ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  document.write(byteOut);
  byteOut.flush();
  byte[] zipData = byteOut.toByteArray();

  zipData = clearZIPEntryLastModified(zipData);

  return zipData;
 }

 static byte[] clearZIPEntryLastModified(byte[] zipData) throws Exception {
  File tmpZipFile = File.createTempFile("zip", ".tmp");
  tmpZipFile.deleteOnExit();

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(tmpZipFile);
  fileOut.write(zipData);
  fileOut.close();

  ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(tmpZipFile);
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(byteOut);
  for(Enumeration enumeration = zipFile.entries(); enumeration.hasMoreElements(); ) {
   ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) enumeration.nextElement();
   entry.setTime(new GregorianCalendar(2019,7,14,21,0,0).getTime().getTime());
   zipOut.putNextEntry(entry);
   InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; int len;
   while ((len = (is.read(buf))) > 0) {
    zipOut.write(buf, 0, (len < buf.length) ? len : buf.length);
   }
   zipOut.closeEntry();
  }
  zipFile.close();
  zipOut.close();
  byteOut.flush();

  return byteOut.toByteArray();
 }

 static void clearDocxMetadata(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  CoreProperties props = document.getProperties().getCoreProperties();
  props.setCreated("2019-08-14T21:00:00z");
  props.setLastModifiedByUser("");
  props.setCreator("");
  props.setLastPrinted("2019-08-14T21:00:00z");
  props.setModified("2019-08-14T21:00:00z");
  document.getProperties().commit();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  byte[] bytes1 = createXWPFZIPArchive();
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  byte[] bytes2 = createXWPFZIPArchive();
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes1.length; i++) {
   byte b1 = bytes1[i];
   byte b2 = 0;
   if (i < bytes2.length) b2 = bytes2[i];
   String sb1 = String.format("%02x", b1);
   String sb2 = String.format("%02x", b2);
   String att = "";if (b1 != b2) att="!";
   if (i == 0 || i % 8 != 0) {
    System.out.print(att+sb1+":"+sb2+"\t");
   } else {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(att+sb1+":"+sb2+"\t");
   }
  }
  System.out.println();

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Word1.docx");
  fileOut.write(bytes1);
  fileOut.close();

  fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Word2.docx");
  fileOut.write(bytes2);
  fileOut.close();

 }
}
```

If you comment out the code line:

```
  zipData = clearZIPEntryLastModified(zipData);
```

to

```
 //zipData = clearZIPEntryLastModified(zipData);
```

you will find the output differ in exact the bytes of the last modified file date and time of all the entries in the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive.